# how to send the value of a textbox from one page to another using querystring

Tags: asp.net

I have a page1 and link on that page which opens up the Page2. There is a textbox on Page1 whose value needs to be passed onto the Page 2 when the user clicks on the link for Page2.

Firstly, I thought of using onTextbox changed event, but cant use that as the values in the textbox are autogenerated.

Once the Page1 is loaded the value in the textbox is 1 which needs to be passed onto Page2 when Page2 is clicked.
i want to do this using querystring.
inputs please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily do that with a LinkButton.  Handle the click event on the LinkButton for Page2, and then construct your Response.Redirect with the appropriate QueryString key/value pairs:

**HTML:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Page2" />
```

**CODE-BEHIND:**

```
Private Sub LinkButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LinkButton1.Click
    Response.Redirect(String.Format("Page2.aspx?tb={0}", Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox1.Text)))
End Sub
```

Comment: I did it as LinkButton9.Attributes.Add("onclick", "httpPage2.aspx?index=1"); it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: @Janet - Sorry, I had to leave work yesterday and just saw this. Yea, adding the client-side onclick to the LinkButton doesn't really make much sense since the whole reason you use the LinkButton is so that you can handle its click event server-side.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) and handle its click event in codebind. There you can [Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28VS.80%29.aspx) to Page2 and append the TextBox' Text to the QueryString.

```
Dim newLink as String = _
   String.Format("Page2.aspx?TextBox1Text={0}", Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox1.Text))
Response.Redirect(newLink)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use POST and Server.Transfer?

Using Server.Transfer then you can get access to all form properties from the previous page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I agree with you, but my supervisor wants me do it with query string. Could you help me with a sample code to achieve this as I am new to this.

Comment: @Janet - does your supervisor know that by exposing the form value within a querystring it pretty much makes this a pointless exercise? After all, I can just change the QS value and request the page again.